# passing arguments to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

This is a javascript function

```
<script>
function func1(var g){
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

how to pass value 0 from function call to  function definition above.

```
<p onmouseover="func1(0)";>First para</p>
```

Comment: That's a JavaScript syntax error, to be more accurate. You can't have that `var` keyword in the formal parameter list. Keep your browser's developer console open so that you can see error messages.

Comment: OP, what is `g` meant to be doing in that function? At the moment it seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
<script>
function func1(g){
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

You need to see console log for relevant errors that pop up.

In this case you are declaring variable in function arguments which is not allowed, you can find out more about `function` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

Comment: The question remains - why pass in that parameter if it's not going to be used unless `g` is meant to replace the index.

Comment: Though it will work for sure.. You must have valid description which will make OP understand things! _Change it/Try this_ will not help the cause...

Comment: No - he's clearly targeting the "First para" which is index 0.

Comment: We can create lots of use cases, OP should answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `[0]` to target the first paragraph when you mouseover it your function should be;

```
function func1(g){
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[g].innerHTML);
}
```

A more canonical JS approach is to attach an event listener to your elements with JavaScript instead of inlining the code:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

[].slice.call(paras).forEach(function (el, i) {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', func1.bind(func1, i), false);
});

function func1(g){
  console.log(paras[g].innerHTML);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/socwhx23/2/)

But perhaps the best way is to use event delegation so that you're not adding listeners to *all* the elements. Add an event listener to *a parent element* and catch the events from the paras as they bubble up the DOM:

```
var div = document.getElementById('paras');

div.addEventListener('mouseover', func1, false);

function func1(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el.nodeType === 1 && el.nodeName === 'P') {
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/101fwqnc/2/)